# How do I check if the quadratic probing is going into an infinite loop?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am writing a program on hashing and resolving collisions using quadratic probing. When I insert keys ending with the same digit repeatedly it goes into an infinite loop for some key. This means that the value cannot be inserted into the hash table. Whenever this occurs, I want to notify the user that the key cannot be inserted into the hash table. How do I set the condition for this in code. This is my function for quadratic probing.

```
/*Here el is the element to be inserted and loc is the value of hash function and size is 
  10*/  
void quadratic(int el)
{
    int loc=el%size;
    int i=0;
    while(hash[loc])
    {
        if(hash[loc]==el)
        {
            printf("This key is already present in the table\n");
            return;
        }
        if(i==0)
            printf("Collision at %d\n",loc );
        else
            printf("%dth probe at %d\n",i,(loc+i*i)%7);
        loc=(loc+i*i)%7;

        i++;
    }
    hash[loc]=el;
}
```

Comment: inside the while loop, for the 2nd cycle onwards, `loc` will be `0` to `6`. Just clear a bit in a flag (`unsigned flag = (1<<7) - 1;`) and test... `flag &= ~(1 << loc); if (!flag) { /* all loc values tested */ }`

Comment: You could compare the number of probes against the size of the table. If the number of probes exceeds the size, then you have an infinite loop. Or your probing is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it from going into an infinite loop with a cool math trick.

First, make sure the size of your map is 3 mod 4.

Then, instead of adding 1, 4, 9, ...

add 1, -4, 9, -16, ...

This will visit every space in the map!